# has no member named c++

Tags: c++, stack, member, named

I have some problem. I created program with dynamic stack and when I compiling get errors: **'class stos' has no member named 'push' , 'class stos' has no member named 'pop' , 'class stos' has no member named 'destroy' , 'class stos' has no member named 'isempty'**. In language C program is fine, but in C++ not. I have started my adventure with C++ and I don't have idea what's wrong I do. Can you help me ?  I'm putting a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class stos
{
public:
int *tab;
int licznik;
int rozmiar;

};

void init (class stos* s)
{
s->licznik = 0;
s->rozmiar = 3;
//s->tab = (int*) malloc ( 2 * sizeof * s->tab );
s->tab = (int*) malloc ( s->rozmiar * sizeof(int) );
if (s->tab == NULL)
    {
    cout << "Blad alokacji pamieci\n";
    abort ();
    }
}

void push (class stos* s, int element) 
{
if (s->licznik != s->rozmiar)
    {
    cout << "Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    s->tab[s->licznik] = element;
    s->licznik++;
    }
else
{
    s->rozmiar = 2 * (s->rozmiar);
    s->tab = (int*) realloc (s->tab, (s->rozmiar) * sizeof (int));
    cout << "Zwiekszono pamiec\n";
    cout <<"Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    s->tab[s->licznik] = element;
    s->licznik++;
}
//system ("clear");
}

int pop (class stos* s) 
{
if (s->licznik == 0)
{
    cout << "Nie podales zadnego elementu\n";
    abort ();
}
else
{
    s->licznik--;
}
return s->tab[s->licznik];
}

void destroy (class stos* s)
{

  free (s->tab);

}

bool isempty (class stos* s)
{   
bool empty = true;

if (s->licznik == 0)
    {
  empty = true;
  cout << "Stos nie posiada zadnych elementow\n";
    }
else
    {
  empty = false;
  cout << "Stos zawiera jakies elementy\n";
    }
return empty;
}

int main () 
{
int element = 0, a = 0;
 stos stos1;
 stos stos2;


    do
    {
    cout << "\nMENU\n\n";
    cout << "STOS I\nAby dodac element do stosu wcisnij '1'\nAby odjac element ze stosu wcisnij '2'\n";
    cout << "Wcisnij '3' aby usunac stos\nWcisnij '4' aby sprawdzic czy stos zawiera elementy\n\n";
    cout << "STOS II\nAby dodac element do stosu wcisnij '5'\nAby odjac element ze stosu wcisnij '6'\n";
    cout << "Wcisnij '7' aby usunac stos\nWcisnij '8' aby sprawdzic czy stos zawiera elementy\n\n";
    cout << "Wcisnij '0' aby zakonczyc dzialanie programu\n\n";
    cin >> a;
    //system ("clear");

    if (a == 1)
    {
        stos1.push (element); 
    }
    if (a == 2)
    {
        cout << "Usunieto element:" << stos1.pop;

    }
    /*if (a == 3)
    {
        destroy (&stos1);
        printf ("Wyczyszczono stos 1\n");
    }*/
    if (a == 4)
    {
        stos1.isempty;
    }
    if (a == 5)
    {
        stos2.push (element);
    }
    if (a == 6)
    {
        cout << "Usunieto element: " << stos2.pop;

    }
    /*if (a == 7)
    {
        destroy (&stos2);
        printf("Wyczyszczono stos 2\n");
    }*/

    if (a == 8)
    {
        stos2.isempty;
    }
}
while (a!=0);
    destroy (&stos1);
    destroy (&stos2);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "In language C program is fine" - huh? I assume you're talking about a different code...

Comment: C++ allows you to define member functions that you could call using syntax like stos1.push(), but you haven't defined any. C++ doesnt change the way you call a C-style function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the functions `stos`, `push`, etc. are free functions, but you call them like methods. You need to call them this way:

```
stos s;
init(&s)
push(&s, 3)
```

Or better, you can convert the functions to methods:

```
class stos {
public:
    stos() // constructor instead of init
    {
        // access members tab, etc. directly
        licznik = 0;
        // ...
    }

    void push(int element)
    {
    }

    // ...
private:
    int *tab;
    int licznik;
    int rozmiar;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "class stos has no member named push" and so on. `push` and `pop` are non-member functions. It looks like you need something of the form

```
push (&stos, element);
```

and

```
pop(&stos1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you declare the class `stos`. The class only contains some fields.

Later in your code you define the functions

```
void push (class stos* s, int element)
int pop (class stos* s)
bool isempty (class stos* s)
```

Basically this is correct. You could just create an instance of the class `stos` and then call one of the functions and pass the `stos` instance as an argument of the function. In this case you need to make the function call like this:

```
push (stos1, element);
```

instead of:

```
stos1.push (element);
```

The other way is as others may already have suggested is to add the functions to your class. In that case your class definition would look like this:

```
class stos
{
public:
int *tab;
int licznik;
int rozmiar;

void push (int element)
int pop ()
bool isempty ()
};
```

If you create the class like this you can leave the function calls in your main as they are now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have member functions you have to write them for instance push could be written like this

```
class stos
{
public:
void push (int element);
int *tab;
int licznik;
int rozmiar;

};

void stos::push (int element) 
{
if (licznik != rozmiar)
    {
    cout << "Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    tab[licznik] = element;
    licznik++;
    }
else
{
    rozmiar = 2 * (rozmiar);
    tab = (int*) realloc (tab, (rozmiar) * sizeof (int));
    cout << "Zwiekszono pamiec\n";
    cout <<"Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    tab[licznik] = element;
    licznik++;
}
//system ("clear");
}
```

This looks like code which has been translated from C, but you have only gone half way.

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are trying to call are not in class `stos`
You could do something like this:

```
class stos
{
public:
int *tab;
int licznik;
int rozmiar;

void init ();
void push (int element);
int pop ();
void destroy ();
bool isempty ()

};

void stos:: init ()
{
this->licznik = 0;
this->rozmiar = 3;
//this->tab = (int*) malloc ( 2 * sizeof * this->tab );
this->tab = (int*) malloc ( this->rozmiar * sizeof(int) );
if (this->tab == NULL)
    {
    cout << "Blad alokacji pamieci\n";
    abort ();
    }
}

void stos:: push (int element) 
{
if (this->licznik != this->rozmiar)
    {
    cout << "Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    this->tab[this->licznik] = element;
    this->licznik++;
    }
else
{
    this->rozmiar = 2 * (this->rozmiar);
    this->tab = (int*) realloc (this->tab, (this->rozmiar) * sizeof (int));
    cout << "Zwiekszono pamiec\n";
    cout <<"Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    this->tab[this->licznik] = element;
    this->licznik++;
}
//system ("clear");
}

int stos:: pop () 
{
if (this->licznik == 0)
{
    cout << "Nie podales zadnego elementu\n";
    abort ();
}
else
{
    this->licznik--;
}
return this->tab[this->licznik];
}

void stos:: destroy ()
{

  free (this->tab);

}

bool stos:: isempty ()
{   
bool empty = true;

if (this->licznik == 0)
    {
  empty = true;
  cout << "Stos nie posiada zadnych elementow\n";
    }
else
    {
  empty = false;
  cout << "Stos zawiera jakies elementy\n";
    }
return empty;
}
```

Comment: If you make those functions methods you should also drop the `s` parameter and instead access the instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Class `stos` has no one of these member functions, looking into your code I think that you've two possible solutions. Or you add it to class stos, something like:

```
class stos
{
public:
int *tab;
int licznik;
int rozmiar;

void init ()
{
s->licznik = 0;
s->rozmiar = 3;
//s->tab = (int*) malloc ( 2 * sizeof * s->tab );
s->tab = (int*) malloc ( s->rozmiar * sizeof(int) );
if (s->tab == NULL)
    {
    cout << "Blad alokacji pamieci\n";
    abort ();
    }
}

void push (int element) 
{
if (s->licznik != s->rozmiar)
    {
    cout << "Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    s->tab[s->licznik] = element;
    s->licznik++;
    }
else
{
    s->rozmiar = 2 * (s->rozmiar);
    s->tab = (int*) realloc (s->tab, (s->rozmiar) * sizeof (int));
    cout << "Zwiekszono pamiec\n";
    cout <<"Dodaj element do stosu\n";
    cin >> element;
    s->tab[s->licznik] = element;
    s->licznik++;
}
//system ("clear");
}
...
};
```

or you call them in the right way:

```
push(&stos1, element);
```

instead of

```
stos1.push(element);
```

On the other hand, if you decide not to include them into `stos` class, please, consider using references instead of pointers:

```
void push (class stos& s, int element);
```

*Use reference wherever you can, pointers wherever you must.* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just giving hint for the "pop" problem:

Make it a method of class stos:

```
class stos
{
public:
int *tab;
int licznik;
int rozmiar;
int pop( void );
};
```

Implement the method:

```
int stos::pop (void ) 
{
    if (licznik == 0)
    {
        cout << "Nie podales zadnego elementu\n";
        abort ();
    }
    else
    {
        licznik--;
    }
    return tab[licznik];
}
```

But you should really learn more about `class` before going further